# Moving React Reanimated animation logic to hook causes an error

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-reanimated

I'm expecting a problem with React Native Reanimated code. The code works as it is placed in the component itself, but after I have finished work, I wanted to move animation logic to separate hook for readability sake.

The problem is whenever I move the code to the hook, I'm experiencing:

```
ReanimatedError: [Reanimated] Tried to synchronously call a non-worklet function on the UI thread.
```

Moving it back to the component makes it working again.

The animation code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Dimensions, Easing } from "react-native";
import { runOnJS, useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withTiming } from "react-native-reanimated";

const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('screen').width;

export const useWelcomeSlider = () => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const [final, setFinal] = useState(false);
  const strokeRotation = useSharedValue(-20);
  const fillRotation = useSharedValue(0);
  const imageOpacity = useSharedValue(1);

  const strokeStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{ rotate: `${strokeRotation.value}deg` }],
    };
  }, [strokeRotation]);

  const fillStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{ rotate: `${fillRotation.value}deg` }],
    };
  }, [fillRotation]);

  const imageStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      opacity: imageOpacity.value,
    };
  }, [imageOpacity]);

  const buttonStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    width: withTiming(step < 2 ? 86 : screenWidth - 32, { duration: 200 }, () => {
      if (step === 2) {
        runOnJS(setFinal)(true);
      }
    }),
  }));

  const handleStepChange = () => {
    const strokeTargetRotation = (step + 1) * 20;
    const fillTargetRotation = (step + 1) * 20;
    strokeRotation.value = withTiming(strokeTargetRotation, {
      duration: 300,
      easing: Easing.linear,
    });

    fillRotation.value = withTiming(
      fillTargetRotation,
      {
        duration: 500,
        easing: Easing.linear,
      },
      () => {
        imageOpacity.value = withTiming(1, { duration: 200 });
      },
    );

    imageOpacity.value = withTiming(0, { duration: 200 }, () => {
      runOnJS(setStep)(step + 1);
      imageOpacity.value = withTiming(1, { duration: 500 });
    });
  };


  return {
    strokeStyle,
    fillStyle,
    imageStyle,
    buttonStyle,
    final,
    step,
    handleStepChange
  }
}
```

and the working code:

```
export const Welcome = () => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const [final, setFinal] = useState(false);
  const strokeRotation = useSharedValue(-20);
  const fillRotation = useSharedValue(0);
  const imageOpacity = useSharedValue(1);

  // ref
  const bottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);

  const strokeStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{rotate: `${strokeRotation.value}deg`}],
    };
  });

  const fillStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{rotate: `${fillRotation.value}deg`}],
    };
  });

  const imageStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      opacity: imageOpacity.value,
    };
  });

  const buttonStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    width: withTiming(step < 2 ? 86 : screenWidth - 32, {duration: 200}, () => {
      if (step === 2) {
        runOnJS(setFinal)(true);
      }
    }),
  }));

  const handleStepChange = (stepModifier: number) => {
    const nextStep = step + stepModifier;
    if (nextStep < 0 || nextStep > 2) {
      bottomSheetRef.current?.present();
      return;
    }
    const strokeTargetRotation = (step + 1) * 20;
    const fillTargetRotation = (step + 1) * 20;
    strokeRotation.value = withTiming(strokeTargetRotation, {
      duration: 300,
      easing: Easing.linear,
    });

    fillRotation.value = withTiming(
      fillTargetRotation,
      {
        duration: 500,
        easing: Easing.linear,
      },
      () => {
        imageOpacity.value = withTiming(1, {duration: 200});
      },
    );

    imageOpacity.value = withTiming(0, {duration: 200}, () => {
      runOnJS(setStep)(step + stepModifier);
      imageOpacity.value = withTiming(1, {duration: 500});
    });
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{paddingTop: 100, flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
      <Presentation>
        <Animated.View style={[fillStyle, {position: 'absolute'}]}>
          <BlobFill />
        </Animated.View>
        <Animated.Image
          style={[imageStyle, {position: 'absolute', ...imagesSizes[step]}]}
          source={imagesSources[step]}
        />
        <Animated.View style={[strokeStyle, {position: 'absolute', top: 20}]}>
          <BlobStroke />
        </Animated.View>
      </Presentation>

      <StepInfo>
        <Heading></Heading>
        <Description>
         
        </Description>
      </StepInfo>
      <StepIndicator step={step} />
      <Footer>
        <AnimatedButton
          size="large"
          label={!final ? '' : ''}
          onPress={() => handleStepChange(1)}
          style={buttonStyle}
        />
      </Footer>
      <BottomSheetModal
        backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}
        ref={bottomSheetRef}
        index={0}
        snapPoints={['25%']}>
        <View style={{gap: 12, paddingHorizontal: 24, paddingTop: 24}}>
          <Button size="large" label="" onPress={() => {}} />
          <Button
            variant="secondary"
            size="large"
            label=""
            onPress={() => {}}
          />
        </View>
      </BottomSheetModal>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Why it behaves differently? What changed when I moved the code to the hook, could somebody explain?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution pls? I'm in the exact same situation.